# Postgresql: change default data path

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I would like to point the PostgreSQL server to a particular non-default data directory upon startup. Right now, I have to (either manually or in a script) use pg_ctl to stop and restart the database with my `/new/path/to/data`.

OS is Ubuntu where the default data directory is `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open  `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf`and adjust [data_directory](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html#GUC-DATA-DIRECTORY) property to your new data path and restart the server using (preffered) `pg_ctlcluster 8.4 main stop/start` or [pg_ctl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-pg-ctl.html) if you want in that way.

Make sure that `/new/path/to/data` is accessible only for postgres user:

```
chown postgres.postgres /new/path/to/data
chmod 700 /new/path/to/data
```

Comment: Note that you must move the data directory (or do a new `initdb` to create a new cluster) or Postgres will throw a fit...

Comment: Yap, must move or copy data from previous directory to that new before server start (don't try to move or copy data if postmaster is still running using previous dir).

Comment: yes - stop, move, then restart. Otherwise the universe will end (Or your database will be corrupted beyond the point of repair. Not a good thing either way)

Comment: I tried this, and additionally pointed `hba_file` and `ident_file` to the same directory.  Now the postgres server does not run at startup.  The new data directory was previously created with `initdb`.  (I don't need to copy the old one.) What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your output from pg_lsclusters command ?

Comment: showing the new data location but down status: `8.4     main      5432 down   postgres /mnt/pgsql-db/Database            /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log'

Comment: in the log it says fatal because there is group/world access.  I will change the permissions.

Comment: Right, so I updated my answer on this.

Comment: Now I'm getting fatal: could not load server certificate file "server.crt": no such file or directory.

Comment: If you don't use SSL connections, then simply turn off ssl property in postgresql.conf. If you need SSL, then make symbolic link server.crt in data directory as server.crt -> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem. Also you need root.crt -> /etc/postgresql-common/root.crt and server.key -> /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key as well there.

Comment: Point taken.  Before your last comment I copied server.crt and server.key over to my new directory.  Database server is now online upon booting up.  Thanks for all your help!